# How to install debian through LAN?

Tags: linux, debian, system-installation, lan

I have 2 computers PC1 and PC2

1) PC1 can't boot from CD-ROM or USB, the only way is to boot from **LAN**

2) PC2 is runing debian jessie (which I want to use as server) and contains the Iso image **debian8.iso**,

How to install debian jessie on my PC1 through **LAN** using the **debian8.iso** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a PXE Boot server.  You can do this using several operating systems, including Debian.

PC2 is configured as a PXE Boot server, potentially using resources from the ISO image.  PC1 is then configured in the BIOS to boot from those resources.

There's a lot of stuff required on PC2 to support this, and PC1 needs to support network booting from the BIOS as well.

There's a long write-up on the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall), I'll try to summarise it (but the process is quite complex).

- PC2 is your Server.
- You need to install a DHCP service on your server, and configure it to allow booting.
- You need to install a TFTP service on your server.
- You need to get a network boot image, and configure it as a resource within the TFTP service.  You can do this using apt on PC2 (the package is known as debian-installer-$VERSION-netboot-$ARCH where $VERSION in your case is 8 and $ARCH needs to match your *target* machines architecture).
- On your client (PC1) you need to configure the network boot to point at PC2, reboot PC1 and if you've got everything configured correctly it should boot.

Read the Wiki I linked, it has more detail.